# Add additional links response to knowledge base in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

With knowledge bases in DialogFlow you can have a basic FAQ upload. First column is the question and second is the answer. Often we need to have the answer provide an additional link. e.g., "The answer to your question is no, pineapple does not go on pizza". [More info](https://www.mashed.com/183299/the-most-controversial-pizza-toppings-explained/)

What I want to provide is the answer followed by a rich response link. Since you cannot have a 3rd column in the spreadsheet to add a link, how can I do this cleanly? Sure, I can just have the link as part of the answer text, but that's not as pretty.

I was able to duplicate the question and then provide a link as the second answer (i.e., $Knowledge.Answer(2)) but then some answers don't have links and I can't make this conditional.

I assume I can do this in Fulfilment but I'm not sure of the actual code that can return the answer ($Knowledge.Answer(1)) and then conditionally add a rich response with a link.

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked it out.

First, I used some delimiter in my answer (here just 'Z$Z').

For example, in the csv file I put the following in a second column:

The answer to your question is no, pineapple does not go on pizza$Z$More Info$Z$https://www.mashed.com/183299/the-most-controversial-pizza-toppings-explained/

This way when I get to the fulfillment I can just parse the answer.
Here's a cut of the code:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  // save off the answer to parse
  let answer = JSON.stringify(request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText);   
  
  function faqHandler(agent) {
    let answerAlt = answer.slice(1,-1); // remove first and last double quote
    let answerParse = answerAlt.split("Z$Z"); // parse the answer
    if( answerParse.length == 1) {
      // no links
      agent.add(answerParse[0].toString());
    } else {
      // display the content with the text and links
      // you can use different ways here to display but you have access to
      // the answer, title, and url as follows
      // answerParse[0].toString(), answerParse[1].toString(), answerParse[1].toString()
    }
  }
  ...
  intentMap.set('Knowledge.KnowledgeBase.ID_OF_KNOWLEDGEBASE',faqHandler);
```